# Jsonwebtoken not working as expected JWT Expired

Tags: javascript, express, jwt

Hello can some help with this, I can't seems to figure out why I always got en error `TokenExpiredError: jwt expired` I just created the token.

Here's what I wanted to do.

1.) when user logged in, response contains the accessToken and refreshToken

2.) call the auth/token every 30 seconds to generate new accessToken.

auth/token api will accept refresh_token as request data and the accessToken as Bearer Authorization, however in I always got `jwt expired`. It fails on the authentication middleware.

However when I used the accessToken I got from logged in api, I got `jwt expired` error.

`JWT Service`

```
sign(payload, expiresIn = '15m') {
  return jwt.sign(payload, this.privateKey, {
    algorithm: 'RS256',
    expiresIn,
  });
}

verify(token) {
   return jwt.verify(token, this.publicKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });
}
```

`Controller.js`

```
 // login api
login(req, res, next) {
const { body: { email, password } } = req;

this.accountService.findByEmail(email)
  .then(async (data) => {

    const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign({ data}, '2m');
    const refreshToken = this.jwtService.sign({ data}, '1h');

    return res.send(new SuccessResponse(200, {accessToken, refreshToken}));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    next(error);
  });
 }
}


 // auth/token api
 authToken(req, res, next) {
     const { body: { refresh_token } }= req;
     const payload = { refresh_token };
     const newAccessToken = this.jwtService.sign({ payload }, '1m', 'RS256');
 }
```

`authenticate.middleware.js`

```
export const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorizationBearer = req.get('authorization');
  const accessToken = authorizationBearer.replace('Bearer ', ''); 
  const decodedData = jwtService.verify(accessToken);

  if (decodedData) {
     next();
  }
}
```

Did I miss something or did I do anything wrong?

Library Used:

`jsonwebtoken: 8.5.1`
`express: 4.17.1`

Comment: how does the actual token look like?

Comment: @jps something ike this `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbXBEYXRhIjp7ImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiYWNjb3VudF9pZCI6IjVmNTBjMTIwNDhlZmIxMDZlOTk5ZThlNSJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1OTkzMDcyNzIsImV4cCI6MTU5OTMwNzU3Mn0.r09RrfUjjJCm3ZyZ71xuN9U8o-1xR4s_Kt_ir6OQ6CkBuewPJiExiN_MgnFuTIf74M_r6q4auzpErE6hWfJL49UCNPX_zb9cN8DafaCmScfxz1JIGtBoD22sCcs7id8Td1rsLt3VBfP65OCdkkukXHNg0ccvrhO-VdbjFGmUhNYnudrHdCEpz59_3HkXjklQqn8Yh--fYX2Ds0pSUy8yfs3knBJIz4GD4wLoyP9bwxVaqo-IVLX-sEtzQUv3J_9wT7YlYdZGPoVxWSJwmxXMLP42ILKuh_9x1Ekpa7t54wQ6cqxkq6tjp6d7g0TNlaigoXc2dDCJ_wArDOZPcHvuxg`

Comment: The format is correct so  I don't know why I always get Jwt Expired error

Comment: ok, exp and iat look fine.

Comment: yeah, I've been stack here for hours already but I still couldn't find out what what I miss.